# Python >=3.5.3 on Synology

Tags: python, synology

i am trying to install Home Automatization (https://home-assistant.io) on my Synology. I've installed python via the synology packaging system, i've done basic setup (https://home-assistant.io/docs/installation/synology/) but when i try to run the daemon i see this in console:

*homeassistant requires Python '>=3.5.3' but the running Python is 3.5.1*

Is there any chance to update the python to required version on synology? Can you help me please?

Comment: Reinstall python, maybe with another package manager if yours doesn't support a newer version.

Comment: I am Linux noob, so I am not sure how. Synology support Python up to 3.5.1 and newer version isn't availible.

Comment: try 'sudo apt install python'. I am not sure what exact packages there are for python, but this should do it.

Comment: Tried it, but I get: "sudo: apt: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

Synology offers only python 3.5.1 at the moment.
You need to install older version of HA as mentioned on the installation page in blue box.
./python3 -m pip install homeassistant==0.64.3

If you would like to install latest HA, you would need to use docker instances on Synology, if your model supports it.

BTW.
Since the Python3 update (3.5.1-108) on Synology. once you install the HA you need to edit two files.
/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/hass
and 
/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/runpy.py

and add "import pip" to the beginning of the file where the import statements are. Otherwise HA will not start.

Answer (score 0):

I've provided an updated [python3-3.5.6](https://synocommunity.com/package/python3) SPK for Synology in SynoCommunity; python3-3.6.8 is in the pipeline.  Consider [adding SynoCommunity](https://synocommunity.com/#easy-install) ("spksrc") to your NAS to seamlessly install updates.

Additionally, be aware that [home-assistant-0.82](https://synocommunity.com/package/homeassistant) is in beta at the same site.

Raw SPKs can be manually downloaded from [my beta site](http://spk.chickenandporn.com/) if you want to check there as well, but I would suggest you look into SynoCommunity, keep updated from there, contribute comments and code there.

Comment: What's the status on python3-3.6.8? 
When I navigate to https://synocommunity.com/packages I see Python3 listed as v3.5.6-8, but https://synocommunity.com/package/python3 tells me Python3 is at v3.6.8-9, as well as maintained by someone else. In other words, the website is in conflict with itself. 
In addition, on my NAS I can only see v3.5.6-8, not v3.6.8-9.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment until recently :(  It's possible that the site listing the available packages gets out-of-sync.  It may not update on packages-removed, only on packages added.

By the time you're reading this, there have been a few iterations on updated python3 by a better maintainer, so I hope everything is fine now.